# How can i transfer data between activities when one activity goes into onPause state?

Tags: java, android

I mean not using Intent putExtra.

When 'A' Activity goes into onPause or onDestroy state, i want to transfer String data type to 'B' Activity.

I'll appreciate with your response.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a static field in class A or make a singleton class that would keep track and override the onPause() method in class A.

Comment: Thanks for quick response!! Does static field downgrade the total program??